# R: using dplyr to do calculation row-wise

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a vector:

```
vec <- c(44,0,13,18,32,13,25,42,13,24)
```

I want to calculate fT as follows:

```
fT <- ifelse(vec >= 10 & vec <= 20, min(vec) - max(vec), 
         ifelse(vec > 20 & vec <= 50, max(vec) - min(vec),0))
```

I want to extent this calculation for each row of a dataframe i.e. 
I have a dataframe and I want to calculate fT for each row.

A sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:50,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

That means I will have another dataframe which will have the fT value for each value in dat.

To calculate fT for each row, I thought of using `dplyr`,

```
dat%>%
  rowwise()%>%
   mutate(fT = ifelse(dat[,1:10] >= 10 & dat[,1:10] <= 30, min(dat[,1:10]) - max(dat[,1:10]), 
                  ifelse(dat[,1:10] > 30 & dat[,1:10] <= 50, max(dat[,1:10]) - min(dat[,1:10]),0)))
```

I am stuck at this stage. I do not know how to index by column so that for each row of `dat`, I have a 
`fT`.

Comment: I believe the problem is that given a vector, your calculation does not yield a vector of length one, but rather a vector of the same length as the input vector. You may want to wrap your conditions in `all()` or `any()` depending on what you want so that you get a single value from that calculation.

Comment: Sorry I meant I want to calculate fT. Question edited now.

Comment: I have edited the question now. fT is the sum of all values coming out of the ifelse statement.

Comment: @duckmayer Good call `dat[,1:10] >= 10 & dat[,1:10]` and similar returns a logical vector of length 10, meaning the `ifelse()` statement will not behave correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the *sums* of `fT`, you can do this with `apply`:

```
dat$fT = apply(dat, 1, function(x) sum(ifelse(x >= 10 & x <= 20, min(x) - max(x), 
                                              ifelse(x > 20 & x <= 50, max(x) - min(x),0))))
```

**Result:**

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10  fT
1 14 13  8 10 15 12 22 47 29  40 -39
2 40 30  7 48 42 50 20 30 24  44 301
3 20  8  7 19 30 36 18  4 37  12 -33
4 45 43 26 31 41 33 26 43 11  28 272
5 47 43 25  9 14 12  3  1 38  46 138
6  2 24 31 33  7  4 36 41 42   0 252
```

**Note:**

`1` in `apply` specifies the row margin. This loops through the rows of the input, `dat`, and output a single sum of `fT` for each row.

**Edit:**

If you actually want the value of `fT` (not the sum), you can still use `apply`, but wrap the output with `matrix` and specify `ncol=10` and `byrow=TRUE`. This means that you want an output matrix with 10 columns (just like `dat`) and fill the matrix rowwise with the output of `apply`:

```
new_dat = matrix(apply(dat, 1, 
                       function(x) ifelse(x >= 10 & x <= 20, min(x) - max(x), 
                                          ifelse(x > 20 & x <= 50, max(x) - min(x),0))),
                 ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

**Result:**

```
> head(new_dat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]  -39  -39    0  -39  -39  -39   39   39   39    39
[2,]   43   43    0   43   43   43  -43   43   43    43
[3,]  -33    0    0  -33   33   33  -33    0   33   -33
[4,]   34   34   34   34   34   34   34   34  -34    34
[5,]   46   46   46    0  -46  -46    0    0   46    46
[6,]    0   42   42   42    0    0   42   42   42     0
```

If you prefer sticking to `dplyr`, you can first `transpose` your `dat` and `map` it on the "columns", then `transpose` back:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  transpose() %>%
  map_dfr(~ ifelse(. >= 10 & . <= 20, min(.) - max(.), 
                  ifelse(. > 20 & . <= 50, max(.) - min(.),0))) %>%
  transpose()
```

**Result:**

```
> head(new_dat2)
   V1  V2 V3  V4  V5  V6  V7 V8  V9 V10
1 -39 -39  0 -39 -39 -39  39 39  39  39
2  43  43  0  43  43  43 -43 43  43  43
3 -33   0  0 -33  33  33 -33  0  33 -33
4  34  34 34  34  34  34  34 34 -34  34
5  46  46 46   0 -46 -46   0  0  46  46
6   0  42 42  42   0   0  42 42  42   0
```

**Note:**

The advantage of using `transpose` instead of `t` in Base R is that you get a data.frame after transposing instead of a matrix.

**Data:**

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:50,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I just realised rather than sum, I need fT for each value i.e. a matrix with same dimension as dat. But this is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `pmax/pmin` which would be efficient

```
m1 <- (do.call(pmax, dat) - do.call(pmin, dat))[row(dat)] 
out <-  (-1*m1 *(dat >=10 & dat <=20)) +   (m1*(dat > 20 & dat <=50))
all.equal(new_dat, out, check.attributes = FALSE)   
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.frame(replicate(500,sample(0:50,15000,rep=TRUE)))

system.time({
new_dat = matrix(apply(dat, 1, 
                       function(x) ifelse(x >= 10 & x <= 20, min(x) - max(x), 
                                          ifelse(x > 20 & x <= 50, max(x) - min(x),0))),
                 ncol =  ncol(dat), byrow = TRUE)
  })
#user  system elapsed 
#   2.67    0.10    2.77 
system.time({
   m1 <- (do.call(pmax, dat) - do.call(pmin, dat))[row(dat)] 
   out <-  (-1*m1 *(dat >=10 & dat <=20)) +   (m1*(dat > 20 & dat <=50))
 })
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.48    0.11    0.60 


#all.equal(new_dat, out, check.attributes = FALSE)   
#[1] TRUE
```